# Use geocomplete function after ajax event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, geocoding, geocomplete

I have a button that adds an input box where you can type an address. For the address, I'm using the [geocomplete plugin](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/). In all input boxes that were not generated with ajax the geocomplete works. If the input was generated by ajax, it doesnt.

This is my code to generate the input box:

```
$('.add-drop').on('click', function(){  
     $.ajax({
         url : '/ajax/get-location-input',
         success : function(data){   
            $('#additional-drop').append(data);
        } 
    }); 
});
```

This is my geocomplete code:

```
$(".get-location").geocomplete({
    details : "form",
    types : ["geocode", "establishment"]
  }).bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){  
      console.log(result);
});
```

The problem is not with the class. I was trying to do something like `$(".get-location").on("geocomplete"...` but it wasn't working. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Put the geo complete code into the `success` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is Asynchronous *(Asynchronous JavaScript and XML)* That means it might execute after the main code has been finished processing

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/get-location-input',
    success:function(data){   
        alert(data);
    } 
});

alert('Hi ');
```

In this case, `Hi` will alert first, then `data`. In your case, the inputs might not even be generated yet and so the `geolocation` code won't see them

The correct code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '$('#additional-drop').append(data);',
    success:function(data){   
        $('#additional-drop').append(data);

        $(".get-location").geocomplete({
            details: "form",
            types: ["geocode", "establishment"]
        });

    } 
});
```

Will make the code run after the data has been fetched from the server

---

This is me recommended way to do this:

```
(function () {

    $.fn.addGeolocation = function () { this.geocomplete({ details: "form", types: ["geocode", "establishment"] }).bind("geocode:result", function(e, a){ console.log(a); }); }

    $.get('/ajax/get-location-input', function (a) {
        $('#additional-drop').append(data);

        $(".get-location").addGeolocation();

    });

    /* You may or may not need this */
    window.onload = function () { $(".get-location").addGeolocation(); }

}());
```